# Can i use the esp8266 SPI with ds1302

Tags: esp8266, spi, arduino-esp8266

I just wanna know is there any possibility to use the spi of the esp8266 to communicate with ds1302 cuz I don't have enough pins to use thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

try to connect it to I2c with other devices in parallel(2 wire) and 1 wire CE is to other port

Answer (score -1):

The `DS1302` module communication standard is by `SPI` (Serial Peripheral Interface) and it has a 3-way bus (known as `3-wire interface`):

`CE` - When at a high level, it enables communication with the microcontroller

`SCK` - Synchronism clock (similar to `I2C` `SCL`)

`I/O` - Data input and output (`I2C` `SDA`)

You can use libraries like `MyRealTimeClock.h` (common in `Arduino IDE` ) to help.

[Reference](https://www.programmersought.com/article/14115192616/).

Comment: @Higor please stop using `code tags` for things that aren't computer code. The name "Arduino IDE" is not part of a program it's just the name of a program.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Boris, but the tags must be used in codes and in words reserved to the subject of the topic, thus avoiding disassociation to the content for a possible translation. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @HigorMaiaConcessa you're wrong. There's no project to translate Stack Overflow answers and if there was, this would not help them and they could figure it out which parts should and shouldn't be translated. `code tags` are just used to visually distinguish parts of text that are computer programs from regular text to make reading easier. I don't really even know what you're talking about.

Comment: Depending on the situation, I use translator to translate the page and I've had problems with reserved words. The community is in English, but that doesn't mean everyone here is fluent in English.